# Ui is not updating on realtime

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, listviewitem

I have a listview for displaying all the items that i getting from api.i have a live event which will modify  one  field inside the item of type  observablecollection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Dyocense.Views.ManageJobs"
             Title="All jobs">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="ADD" Clicked="AddJob"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <SearchBar x:Name="Search" SearchButtonPressed="SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed"></SearchBar>
            <ListView x:Name="JobsListView"   
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             HasUnevenRows="true"
             CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
             ItemAppearing="BrowseJobList_ItemAppearing"
             IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
             >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                <Frame HasShadow="True" >
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Grid>
                                           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                               Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                                               FontSize="Medium"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="Status" 
                                               Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Status}" 
                                               Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                               FontSize="16"/>
                                        <Label Text="Goal" 
                                               Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Goal}" 
                                               Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
                                               FontSize="16" />
                                        <Label Text="Part" 
                                               Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding PartName}" 
                                               Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"
                                               FontSize="16" />
                                        <Label Text="Assembly" 
                                               Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding NodeName}" 
                                               Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"
                                               FontSize="16" />
                                        <Label Text="GoodCount" 
                                               Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding GoodCount}" 
                                               Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <Label Text="RejectCount" 
                                               Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding RejectCount}" 
                                               Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"
                                               FontSize="16" 
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <Label Text="DownTimeCount" 
                                               Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding DownTimeCount}" 
                                               Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2"
                                               FontSize="16" 
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>

                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.Footer>
                    <Grid Padding="6" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">
                         <!--set the footer to have a zero height when invisible--> 
                        <Grid.Triggers>
                            <Trigger TargetType="Grid" Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Grid.Triggers>
                         <!--the loading content--> 
                        <Label Text="Loading..." VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ListView.Footer>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

i want to update the good count on real time. i debugged the code its getting updated in my list but only updating the UI on a user scroll. Here is my viewmodel

```
public class JobViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Job> items;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        public ObservableCollection<Job> Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set
            {

                items = value;
                if (items != value)
                {
                    items = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
                }
            }
        }
 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
}
private void updateJoblistOnEvent(NotificationEntity message)
        {
            var jobId = message.JobId;
            Job job = Items.FirstOrDefault(a => a.JobId.Equals(jobId));

            switch (message.EventCode)
            {


                case MessageTypeEnum.Pulse: //Pulse
                job.GoodCount = job.GoodCount + 1;

                //job.Status = 'Running';
                break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

i am suspecting two things

1. CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" i removed this one that its not updating with scroll also
2. any problem with INotifyPropertyChanged, i tried to remove one item from list its working and updating the ui.i want to update the field inside the item 
   can any one help me

Comment: Where is the code you use to update the data?

Comment: @Gerald Versluis  sorry.i updated the question with that code also

Comment: You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the `Job` object

Comment: @ Gerald Versluis i already declared Items as ObservableCollection<Job> if this is not correct can you guide me to make this work

Comment: This only updates the UI when something changes in the collection, not the objects in that collection. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As deduced from the comments, you need to also implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the `Job` object. Using the `ObservableCollection` only helps for changes in that collection, so when you remove or add a `Job` object, not if something changes *inside* the `Job` object.

So, in your `Job` object do this (code reverse engineered from what you posted):

```
public class Job : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private int goodCount;
   public int GoodCount
   {
       get { return goodCount; }
       set
       {
           if (goodCount != value)
           {
               goodCount = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GoodCount));
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You could remove the `INotifyPropertyChanged` from your `JobViewModel`, but you probably need it there at some point as well

Comment: thank you so much.this worked for me.so if we want to update all the fields   in job object like this,Do  we need to attach OnPropertyChanged()  function for that.Why its worked for me on scroll before?was that due to changing on collection?

Comment: The scroll works because the object is retrieved again when it goes out of the screen and comes in again, therefore updated the values. For each property that you want to use this way you will have to call the `OnPropertyChanged` or have a look at a library like PropertyChanged.Fody